# Matlab: Determine if random variables are i.i.d and uncorrelated

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have observations from 2 variables `Zz = [x y];` where rows are the observations and columns are the variables. I wanted to obtain statistical measures like if they are uncorrelated, i.i.d, mean and variance would like to know if they are independent indentical distribution and uncorrelated.

1. For uncorrelated I  used `corrcoef(Zz)`

   ans =

> ```
>     1.0000     -0.0300
>
>
>    -0.0300       1.0000
> ```

2. To check which pdf they follow, I used the command `hist(Zz)`
3. To check for covariance:

   > > cov(Zz)

   ans =

> ```
>   211.5004   -6.2984
>    -6.2984  208.3215
> ```

What should be the values to determine if the random varaibles are uncorrelated i.i.d and what can I conclude from these results?

Comment: This is a maths/stats question, not a programming problem. Try asking at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some statistical tests on the null hypothesis that the true correlation coefficient ρ is  0. You can check the details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Inference. Matlab provides you with the p-values on this hypothesis, and the upper and lower bounds

```
[R,P,RLO,RUP]=corrcoef(Zz)
```

An example of bootstrap analysis is shown here http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/bootstrp.html

Comment: I got the value of P = 

    1.0000    0.6375;
    0.6375    1.0000   And in my question what does the value of R which is the  correlation coefficients say? If P is small (according to documentation) then the correlation is "significant". What does this mean?

Comment: RLO =

    1.0000   -0.1537;
   -0.1537    1.0000


RUP =

    1.0000    0.0947;
    0.0947    1.0000

Comment: Your null hupothesis rho = 0 cannot be rejected at the 95% confidence level :). Please, take a look here as well http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~norman/blog_articles/p_values.pdf

Comment: Wiki also is a reasonable starting point on use of the p-values http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value